# how to receive updated props in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

could you please tell me how to receive updated props in react js ?.I know `componentWillReceiveProps` is `unsafe` and I tried using `getDerivedStateFromProps` but not work

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/rm30zoonk4

After two second I am updating my state which is passing to `props`

**`Expected output after two second`**

`abcsssss`

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.src !== "") {
      return { src: nextProps.src };
    } else return null;
  }
```

Comment: You're setting `this.state.src` but your render method uses `this.state.name`. You do call `this.test()` when the component is mounted, but never again after that.

Comment: correct ` but I want to call a function `test` .so that it will give expected output `abcssss`

Comment: how to call `test` fuction when new props receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)

componentDidUpdate is invoked anytime the component is about the receive new props or internal state, here you can intervene before the component is rerendered.

So in hello.js, instead of getDerivedState:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.src !== this.props.src) {
    this.test()
  }
}
```

the comparison "if (prevProps.src !== this.props.src)" is done so the component only update if the src prop changed, preventing unnecessary rerenders.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `componentDidUpdate`

> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

```
class Hello extends Component {
    state = {
        name: ""
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.src !== prevProps.src) {
            this.setState({name: this.props.src + 'ssss'});
        }
    }
    render() {
        return <div>{this.state.name}</div>;
    }
}
```